# Missing Map, only marker is visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am having a hard time trying to figure out what is going wrong. I have gone through similar questions on SO, but the solutions mentioned here did not work. One of the popular solution was to enable the 'Google Maps SDK for iOS', however it was already enabled in my case:
[image]

I think I have taken care of everything mentioned in the tutorial by Google, but when I run my app in simulator, this happens :

[image]

Then I checked my console to find this:
[image]

I checked my `bundle ID` to what I entered while generating the key and it's correct, also the key entered in `AppDelegate.m` isn't wrong. Can someone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

`AppDelegate.m` :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"MY-KEY"]; 

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
}
```

`ViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:151.20
                                                             zoom:6];
GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.view = mapView;

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
marker.title = @"Sydney";
marker.snippet = @"Australia";
marker.map = mapView;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: Create new key for your bundle id .

Comment: Please share your appdelegate file.

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: @emresancaktar: Added code

Comment: @ArpitDongre, plz check now.

Comment: You can try generating another key if it's still giving problem.

Comment: @ArpitDongre - Tried, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

once again check your google service key that is valid key are not.
key is not valid map is not showed.

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSyXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"];
```

Comment: after create the project go to Library>Google Maps SDK for iOS>Enable the  Enable, then you can create the api key.

Comment: problem is only in your key, your posted code is right.

Comment: i am also facing the same problem in my app. i solved this type.

Comment: or you can give me your google maps login id,  i can create and give you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things you can try:

1. Include curly braces. For some people it worked:

**`[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"{MY-KEY}"];`**

2. Manually type the API key instead of copying & pasting the key. Sometimes some characters differs in copy paste procedure.
3. If nothing works, make a fresh start.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue and fixed it by generating and enabling the right APIKey for iOS (and not javascript or android) using this link -- [APIKey for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/get-api-key)