# Google map content (using swift) is not displayed on some iPhone devices?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, maps

I am using GSMMapView initialized as custom view. It works on simulator perfectly, but it happens that on some of real devices my map is loaded empty. In that case I can see pin markers, but the map is empty.

I tried generating new API key and everything is still the same. The device that I tried and it doesn't show map was iPhone 7. Somewhere I have found that the problem might be that the app is multi language (mine is), but I am not sure how that can be fixed and what that means.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing Map, only marker is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674743/missing-map-only-marker-is-visible)

Comment: I've already tried it, it's not, @ocanal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone needs an answer, I solved the problem with adding MapKit.framework to 'Linked Frameworks and Libraries' and setting its status to 'Optional'.